# Is is possible for have a single attribute with a list of values assigned to it?

Tags: python, networkx

I want to assign multiple values to a single attribute in NetworkX but every example I can find seems to suggest that a single attribute can only have one value associated to it.

Lets say I have a node called N1 with the following attributes:

```
modifications_flags

total
```

The attribute modification_flags, I would like to be a list of numbers.

E.G

```
modification_flags: 1,2,7,5
```

The reason I want to do this is because, the value of modifications_flags is set by how edges are removed from a graph.

When a edge is removed that previously connected N1 to N2, a modification_flag value is assigned to each node depending on a attribute held by the edge that originally linked to the two nodes.

One node might have multiple edges and each of the edges, if removed, need to pass on a modification value to the node.

I'm currently attempting this by having modification_flags be a string data type and then converting the numerical modification flag value to a string as well then adding it to the end of the modification_flags string.

E.G

```
modification_flags = '1'

modification value to be added (mod_value) = 4

modification_flags = modification_flag + str(mod_value)

modification_flags = '14'
```

I then iterate through the string as if it was a list. While this works for my use case, it would be far better if the attribute modification_flags could be a list of values.

E.G

```
modification_flags = [1,4]
```

Is this possible? Is so could someone please point me to the documentation/provide me with an example of how this would be done?

**Note: I am not trying to get attribute values from a list or dictionary but rather have one attribute *BE* a list**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1, attributelist = [])
G.add_node(2, attributelist = [ 'a', 'b', 6])
G.nodes(data=True)
> NodeDataView({1: {'attributelist': []}, 2: {'attributelist': ['a', 'b', 6]}})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I assume that I could read in a graph from a file (GML or similar) and achieve the same results instead of hard coding attributes)